# Can we add/append CSS class to a reactive form control from a component in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Do we have any option to add/append CSS class to a reactive form control from the component in angular?

Comment: the .css defined in your Component in `styles` or `styleUrls` is applied to all the component: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles. If you ask about ngClass, check the docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1):

The most dynamic way of adding a class to an element from *.ts is to query the element via [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and then use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) API to add a CSS class you need:

```
  @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addClass();
  }

  addClass() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.input.nativeElement, 'my-class');
  }
```

See my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cfdajn) for a full example.

A more simple alternative is binding to [ngClass]:

```
<input [ngClass]="{ 'my-class-1': condition1, 'my-class-2': condition2 }">
```

(`condition1` and `condition2` are to be defined in your *.ts and return boolean value)

or

```
<input [ngClass]="classProvider">
```

where classProvider is a function, getter or just a property:

```
classProvider() {
    return 'my-class';
}

get classProvider() {
    return 'my-class'
}

classProvider = 'my-class';
```

or just use [class] binding:

```
<input [class.my-class]="condition">
```

where `condition` returns `true` if `my-class` should be applied and `false` if it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make custom css objects in ts, and you can use [ngStyle];

For example

```
//you can do it by statements, or by function, whatever you want
<input [formControlName]="..." [ngStyle]="border()" />
```

in ts:

```
border() {
//you can do whatever you want, pass in value, or variables
return {
   border: '1px solid blue'
   }
}
```